# Can you use GEO IP to display different menus depending on region within one website

Tags: drupal-7, geolocation, geo, megamenu

I work for a business that has offices in 4 regions, UK, US, Dubai and Singapore.  Each region offers slightly different products. I’m planning on using a mega menu dropdown in the primary navigation.

My question is, is it possible to display different menu items depending on what region the user is in? I would’ve thought it would be possible using GEOIP however I’m not sure. I don’t want to build 4 separate websites as the content is virtually the same.

If anyone come across this issue before?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with IP Geolocation using a product such as MaxMind. Depending on your particular needs, you could use a web service, a JavaScript service, or a downloadable database:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/

That said, geolocation is not perfect and you may occasionally display the wrong content to the user. Since having four separate sites seems to be an option, you might want to consider one site with four different country-specific domains and then display the menu based on the domain that the user visits. For instance, this modules seems to do just that:

https://drupal.org/project/domain_menu_access

I am sure there are other modules that can be used in this way.